# rank-1 array error using bode function

Tags: matlab, python, bode

Some time a go i got a matlab script for speaker design. But since i don't use matlab i try to edit to python.
Now i have a problem with the script. Since it is in the bode i was doubting which place i ask the question so it can be the wrong place...

This is basically my script:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w = 2 * np.pi * np.logspace(1,4,401)

c = 340  # speed of sound in air (m/s)
rho = 1.21  # density of air (kg/m^3)

# speaker parameters
B_l = 4.8  # force factor (N/m)
L = 0.15e-03  # inductance (H)
R_dc = 2.7  # DC Resistance (Ohms)
M_m = 6.8e-03  # Total moving mass (kg)
D_m = 0.33  # Damping (kg/s)
K_m = 769.2  # Stiffness (N/m)
a = 120e-03/2  # radius of driver

L_x = .2  # enclosure width (m)
L_z = .25  # enclosure height (m)
L_y = 0.3  # enclosure depth (m)
Vol = L_x * L_y * L_z  # enclosure volume (m^3)

K_enclosure = (np.pi * a ** 2) ** 2 * rho * c ** 2 / Vol  # Stiffness of enclosure
K_tot = K_m + K_enclosure  # total stiffness enclosure

# state space model
As=np.array([[0, 1, 0], [-K_tot / M_m, -D_m / M_m, B_l / M_m], [0, -B_l / L, -(R_dc) / L]])
Bs=np.array([[0, 0, 1 / L]]).T
Cs=np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
Ds=np.array([[0, 0]]).T

w, mag, phase = sig.bode((As, Bs, Cs, Ds), w)
```

The error i receive is:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py:1452: BadCoefficients: Badly conditioned filter coefficients (numerator): the results may be meaningless
  "results may be meaningless", BadCoefficients)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py:901: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  b /= b[0]
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py:901: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  b /= b[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-197-ccaf77289e37>", line 1, in <module>
    w, mag, phase = sig.bode((As, Bs, Cs, Ds), w)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/ltisys.py", line 2398, in bode
    w, y = freqresp(system, w=w, n=n)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/ltisys.py", line 2469, in freqresp
    sys = lti(*system)._as_zpk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/ltisys.py", line 290, in _as_zpk
    return self.to_zpk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/ltisys.py", line 1598, in to_zpk
    **kwargs), **self._dt_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/lti_conversion.py", line 334, in ss2zpk
    return tf2zpk(*ss2tf(A, B, C, D, input=input))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py", line 902, in tf2zpk
    z = roots(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 205, in roots
    raise ValueError("Input must be a rank-1 array.")
ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2802, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2879, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
TypeError: showtraceback() got an unexpected keyword argument 'running_compiled_code'
```

I have alos tried the matlab version on  [octave online](http://octave-online.net).
Also there i get an error message

```
warning: bode: argument(s) number [1 3] are invalid and are being ignored
warning: called from
    __frequency_response__ at line 60 column 5
    bode at line 66 column 16
error: bode: require at least one LTI model
error: called from
    __frequency_response__ at line 65 column 5
    bode at line 66 column 16
```

As last was checkking the ranks of the arrays with `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank()` then i get the following results:

```
np.linalg.matrix_rank(As)
Out[1]: 3
np.linalg.matrix_rank(Bs)
Out[2]: 1
np.linalg.matrix_rank(Cs)
Out[3]: 2
np.linalg.matrix_rank(Ds)
Out[4]: 0
```

I'm a bit surprised why array Ds 0 is and  Bs is 1.

1. The main question is What is wrong with the input that i don't come to a result.
2. Related to this I don't understand how to read in which of the 4 arrays is the problem.
3. If it is part of the problem why Ds is 0  with a lengt of [2 x 1] while Bs is [3 x 1].

All ready thanks for the help!

Comment: What was the **dynamic equations** of the speaker system, from which you obtained As,Bs,Cs, and Ds matrices to obtain the bode plot?

Comment: I'm not sure i answer your'e question. But i have filled the state space model with the parameters...